# Is Atheros AR9485WB-EG capable of packet injection in BackTrack 5?

Tags: linux, code-injection, packet

I found a post that said all Atheros chips support packet injection on Backtrack 5
but when I searched aircrack ng's Compatibility List I couldn't find my driver listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Atheros Supported Adapters (Including yours) are listed at 
http://www.tamos.com/products/commwifi/adapterlist.php
with

`Adapter    802.11 Bands =      2.4 GHz only`

Its clearly written on official site http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers#which_is_the_best_card_to_buy that

`New mac80211 Atheros drivers have native injection and monitoring support`

Hence your device would support packet injection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Atheros AR9485 and almost all other Atheros Drivers have build in wifi support

Reference:
http://aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatible_cards
http://www.tamos.com/products/commwifi/adapterlist.php

Answer (score -1):

> Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter

All Atheros chipsets have native Linux, monitor and packet injection support.